# How can one configure and use MessagePack in an asp.net core 3.1 web api?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, msgpack

I have followed [this article](https://dotnetthoughts.net/using-message-pack-with-asp-net-core/) to start using MessagePack in my asp.net core 3.1 application but it's not working due to the following error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
> 'MessagePack.Resolvers.ContractlessStandardResolver' to
> 'MessagePack.MessagePackSerializerOptions'    Gateway C:\Developments\POC\Gateway\Startup.cs  33  Active

[image]

What is another alternative or solution to fix this compile problem?

Comment: It would really be helpful if you copy paste the code here and not an image.

Comment: Try figuring out what parameters the constructor of `MessagePackOutputFormatter` takes and fill it in. It seems like it needs some sort of Options class of type `MessagePackSerializerOptions`. Try creating that one first and the supply the resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Michael said, what is needed behind `MessagePackOutputFormatter` is the **`MessagePackSerializerOptions`** type, and the current error occurs because the type is ContractlessStandardResolver, **which is not consistent**.

Therefore, you only need to modify the code as follows:

```
 services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(option =>
            {
                option.OutputFormatters.Clear();
                option.OutputFormatters.Add(new MessagePackOutputFormatter(ContractlessStandardResolver.Options));
                option.InputFormatters.Clear();
                option.InputFormatters.Add(new MessagePackInputFormatter(ContractlessStandardResolver.Options));
            })
   .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Comment: I made the changed that you suggested but I get the following error message from the server:

'Invalid response code for http request response NotAcceptable: Not Acceptable'. 

The following code snippet shows how the client prepares the payload string and the header to submit:

var httpContent = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-msgpack");